# How do I use blender masks to make it look like there is magic in my videos

Tags: animation, masking

I'm working on learning how to use masks in blender. I would like to use the masks to make it appear as if there is magic in my videos. Such as when a person in the video lifts they're hand a certain way, magic comes out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be more specific, because as a fellow avid magical enthusiast, there are a plethora of ways you can make magical items. Adding emission to make it glow, adding volumetric shading (volume) around the mask to make it look spooky, a change in texture, and/or even distorting the mask is an effective way to make it look like it reacts to hand movements.

Comment: I was thinking of something that could also be used in fight. One type I want to look like a moving black cloud, the other I want to have a more plasma like look.

Comment: it's too vague, please choose one effect and show a video or a picture

Comment: Sorry, I can't show a picture or video, but for the black cloud, I want to do something similar in the first Descendants where Malificent turns into the dragon, except a lot more like dust when you throw it into the air and a cloud combined. I hope that helps.